# What reason would a military have for large aircraft reasonably co-existance with big rocket powered "flying barges"?

Tags: military, airships, aircraft, air-combat

**Premise**

Having spent a lot of time with Ace-Combat and Highfleet I got to thinking up a table top world a-la Imperial Skies which is set in an alternative 20th century. The setting being developed however, is closer in time to an alternative late cold war era where world superpowers actually build and operate planes such as [the lockheed CL1201 flying carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_CL-1201). I am trying my best to keep things grounded and alternative-historical. The propulsion technology allowing *flying bricks* like in high fleet is being largely hand-waved as some specific efficient thrusters that allow practical jet-alternative to helicopters despite being expensive to operate due to fuel and maintenance.

The weapons technology is cold-war era. So we have cruise missiles, radar, guns of all sorts, etc.

**Question**

That all being said I am looking for plausible reasons for nations to operate both fixed-wing aircraft and what I call "flying barges" which are essentially aesthetically similar to [the ships in highfleet](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2799210333).

Can you throw some serious flaws into this arial coexistence scenario or offer any novel ideas from the POV of a military operation?

**Current thought**

My initial thoughts are fixed wing aircraft are significantly faster and have the advantage of being able to constantly patrol for days on end given aerial refueling, while barges are slower, require more fuel, but are more useful for attacking and breaking a particular position.

[edit]
**More Context**
In a modern fighting scenario we IFVs to take and hold ground as bare infantry was not sufficient. Similarly would large armored flying craft make sense for a military even if their range was more limited? My assumption is built off the same assumption as a US SuperCarrier. Sure it is expensive and could be crippled with a couple missiles, but its usefulness in destroying entire nations is still there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it really "story based" to ask what role a type of vessel might fill in a military? Doesn't WB get those kinds of questions all the time? Maybe if OP rephrased from "*why* would nations operate...?" to "*how* would nations operate...?", though that seems a little pedantic.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand : You have small "classic" planes, giant planes containing planes and these flying barges? What is different between the flying barge and the giant planes?

Comment: Also, people don't build giant planes is the overall cost and existing infrastructures (contrary to aircraft carriers), not so much the fuel cost itself : The CL1201 -like its tank counterpart, the [Ratte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landkreuzer_P._1000_Ratte)- is certainly too big to fit any small-sized airport, and too big to be built in any regular factory. The maintenance to ensure it flies 40 days straight (what allows it to be a mobile base) is insane. Annoyingly, a single good strike at it will lose you easily several billion dollars, both for the plane itself and its content.[...]

Comment: [...] If you think solely about real-world (you likely shouldn't since you're worldbuilding :p), you have to always think strategically when choosing a weapon design : What is the desired effect, short and long-term wise? Is it efficient to reach that goal with that tool? The reason the CL1201 never existed is on good part due to the existence of cheaper aircraft carriers who perform much better. This and the brutal efficiency of nuclear warheads and its shift to modern, cold warfare (cf. [deterrence theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterrence_theory#Nuclear_deterrence_theory)).

Comment: Thanks for the support and answers guys. I was pretty sure my question would be valid, but was kind disappointed when it was immediately closed. 

As for the clarification to @Tortliena yeah we have classic fighters/bombers, we have big CL1201 type aircraft that are used as basically flying power projectors. And now more recently due to "magic jet/rocket engine tech" we have started using increasingly large but slow flying bricks essentially which are used to take and hold ground.
In my universe version of the cold war, proxy wars a-la vietnam are far more common and are fought more openly.

Comment: @knyaz Don't know whether that's worth clarifying that in the question, but I got it. You have my vote to reopen (only 1 left!).You might want to be careful about making many more proxy wars though : the hotter it gets the closer you will be to [DEFCON-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFCON) ☢️.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it all makes sense in-world. But looks like this isn't going to be opened. I don't really understand the subtlety of "too-story-based" here, but thanks for trying!